# syncing folder after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, redmine

Everytime I deploy my redmine repository with capistrano my files are gone. I can see that capistrano symlinks the public directory, but not the {ROOT}/files directory.

I've read some articles on the internet but can't seem to get it work.

So I want is to keep my files in the {APPROOT/files} directory after a deploy

Many thanks for reading this.

Comment: Could you post your capistrano config (remove the server names, repositories, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions:

1: Put your `files` directory in `public/shared`, which persists over the deployments.

2: Add a task in your capistrano recipe to create the symlink after each deploy:

```
task :create_files_symlink, :roles => :app do
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/files #{release_path}/files"
end

after 'deploy:update_code', 'create_files_symlink'
```

Comment: yes, the same principle as symlink of **yml** files specific to current server, it's the common practice

Comment: yep, there's also the database config, which should ideally not be in your code repository.